Why res.clearCookie() is not working after deploying to vercel?
First of all, everything works fine when running on localhost.
However, after deploying the app to Vercel when the user tries to log out it should clear cookies with res.clearCookie() but it doesn't and when the page is refreshed the user remains logged in.
Also, after deploying the app to Vercel the new token is generating fine but is not being stored in the browser's cookies.
here is the function to LogOut
async function userLogout(req,res){
try {
        const tokenOption = {
            httpOnly : true,
            secure : true,
            sameSite : 'None'
        }

        res.clearCookie("token",tokenOption)
        res.clearCookie("refresh_token",tokenOption)

        res.json({
            message: "Logged out successfully",
            error : false,
            success : true,
            data : []

        })
    }catch(err){
    res.json({
        message : err.message || err  ,
        error : true,
        success : false,
      })
     }
    }

module.exports = userLogout

I tried to debug but it was no luck as my localhost was running everything perfectly

Can you provide a [mcve]?

Hi, Can you please see if the cookie is included in the response header once the request for Token generation is executed. You may be able to check this here :  Chrome Browser / NetWork / Headers / Response Headers. The Set-Cookie is the header we need to inspect here. If Set-Cookie has some value, please see if it has some warning symbol displayed. When you hover over this warning symbol, you may be able to know the reason as well.

I believe you are missing the domain property in your options parameter.
How about you try:
const tokenOption = {
          domain: YOUR_COOKIE_DOMAIN, // (Sub)domain(s) under which the cookie will be accesible
          httpOnly : true, // 
          secure : true,
          sameSite : 'None'
      }

I also believe that you are missing this same domain property at your res.cookie declaration within the login path; that would explain why those cookies don't save in the browser.
At your login path you should use something like this instead for the creation of the cookie:
res.cookie("token", token, {
  sameSite: "None",
  domain: YOUR_COOKIE_DOMAIN, // (Sub)domain(s) under which the cookie will be accesible
  httpOnly: true,
  maxAge: 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  secure: true,
});

// Same for the refresh_token

Do note, you must specify your domain either with a specific subdomain, e.g. www.example.com or if you want your cookie to be accessible for all the subdomains of example.com, then it must be specified like so: .example.com

Hi, "A blank domain name" from a server is a well defined response, as it can be seen in this quote from RFC "...If the server omits the Domain attribute, the user agent will return the cookie only to the origin server." For more, please see datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3 @xxfogs

Hello. That's true; I probably might want to make an edit to the answer to note that, however generally API and website domains differ and this often ends up being the issue.

Hi, Thank you for your update.
